# How to change default image display time different 10 second in vlc media player in c#?

Tags: c#, media-player, vlc

I m using axpluging control for media player in c#. But I want to different duration time for images in vlc media player. I cannot do it . How can I set duration time in playlist ?
I m using this event but it is not working properly. Do you have any suggestion ?:

```
  private void axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerTimeChanged(object sender, AxAXVLC.DVLCEvents_MediaPlayerTimeChangedEvent e)
        {

            try
            {

                //log.append("playlist:" + axVLCPlugin21.playlist.currentItem + "," + TimeFormat(e.time), logdirectory);
                foreach (var item in playeritems)
                {
                    string[] line = item.Split(',');



                    if (axVLCPlugin21.playlist.currentItem == Convert.ToInt32(line[0]) && counter == Convert.ToInt32(line[1]) )
                    {
                        if (line[2] != "1")
                        {
                            log.append("playlist:" + axVLCPlugin21.playlist.currentItem + "," + counter.ToString(), logdirectory);
                            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.next();


                        }

                            counter = 0;

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string logstr = ex.InnerException == null ? "" : ex.InnerException.Message;
                log.append("ERROR:" + ex.Message + "-->" + logstr, logdirectory);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code maybe it can help someone:

axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI,"image",":image-duration=5");